# How do I copy large ranges between workbooks efficiently?

Tags: debugging, excel, copy, copy-paste, vba

i'm writing a copy paste function for a fairly large dataset to be copied from one workbook to a specific sheet in another. I have written the bellow code, in the hope that it will copy paste as efficiently as possible, however during debugging the code was shown not to be working at all, it doesnt copy or paste anything and I dont understand why, does anyone have any ideas / solutions? thanks in advance

```
Windows("TempResults.xlsm").Activate
numofrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Workbooks("TempResults.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "AE" & CStr(numofrows)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Excel Results Extractor V2.xlsm").Sheets("Gate_Results").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: I guess there is a syntax error: should be Range("A2:", "AE" & CStr(numofrows). Missing ":" in original statement. Regards,

Comment: Yes, that could be it, however, upon changing it, I'm now getting error 1004. :S

Comment: @Alex No his syntax is correct, It should work.

Comment: the 1004 error is not occurring anymore, but still no luck with the copying and pasting, with both my own and alex's syntax

Comment: There might other errors as well. It's hard to remotely debug your app based on that limited info you have provided. As a general rule, try to simplify the statement using some hard-coded range (for example A1:C3) to see if it works. Rgds,

Comment: Anyways I solved my own problem by opting for a more clear, multi-line approach, not quite so elegant, but very functional.

        Windows("TempResults.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("a2" , ActiveSheet.Range("ae2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Excel Results Extractor V2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Gate_Results").Activate
    Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
Windows("TempResults.xlsm").Activate
numofrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Workbooks("TempResults.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "AE" & CStr(numofrows)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Excel Results Extractor V2.xlsm").Sheets("Gate_Results").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I needed it pasted at the bottom of an already existing table, hence the ".end" function, I should have specified.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the efficiency concern expressed in your question: you can try an alternative approach, like the following:

```
Workbooks("Excel Results Extractor V2.xlsm").Sheets("Gate_Results").Range("A1").Value = Workbooks("TempResults.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Try to see how it works, then modify the range correspondingly to your case.
Hope this will help. Regards,

Comment: Hi, thanks, I solved my problem but opted for less efficiency and more clarity.